# Jquery moving item from select box to table, then back again... not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of unique tasks and underneath it a dropdown list of tasks that can be added.

I want the dropdown list and table to be dynamic because a task cant be in both dropdownlist and table.

So the dropdownlist only containts tasks that are not in the table already.

So if I select a task and click add, it moves to the table (and is no longer in the dropdown). But then if I remove the task from the table it should go back in the dropdown list. This functionality works if the row is already in the table (i.e. in the initial page load), however if I add one to the table and remove it it doesnt go to the dropdown lists.

Here is the js code that moves from dropdown to table

```
$('#addTaskButton').on('click',function() {
    var taskId = $('select[id=processorTasksId]').val();
    if (taskId == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var task = $( "#processorTasksId option:selected" ).text();
    $('#tasksTable').append('<tr><td>' + taskId + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + task + '</td>'
            + '<td contenteditable=\'true\'>0</td>'
            + '<td><input type="button" value="X"></td></tr>');

    $( "#processorTasksId option:selected" ).remove();
});
```

and here is the JS to remove from table.

```
$('#tasksTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(){

       var taskId = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.taskIdCol').text();
       var taskDescription = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.taskDescriptionCol').text();
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       console.log("id = " + taskId);
       console.log("desc = " + taskDescription);

       $('#processorTasksId')
        .append($("<option></option>")
                   .attr("value",taskId)
                   .text(taskDescription));
    });
```

The console log for the problem scenario shows as follows and it just adds an empty option to the dropdown list

```
id = 
desc =
```

Any idea as to how to fix it?

Comment: Please add a fiddle. We need your HTML codes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the missing classes for td's added to the table as part of the script.Check below working code

```js
$(function() {

   $('#addTaskButton').on('click',function() {
    var taskId = $('select[id=processorTasksId]').val();
    if (taskId == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var task = $( "#processorTasksId option:selected" ).text();
    $('#tasksTable').append('<tr><td class="taskIdCol">' + taskId + '</td>'
            + '<td class="taskDescriptionCol">' + task + '</td>'
            + '<td contenteditable=\'true\'>0</td>'
            + '<td><input type="button" value="X"></td></tr>');

    $( "#processorTasksId option:selected" ).remove();
   });

   $('#tasksTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(){

       var taskId = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.taskIdCol').text();
       var taskDescription = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.taskDescriptionCol').text();
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       console.log("id = " + taskId);
       console.log("desc = " + taskDescription);

       $('#processorTasksId')
        .append($("<option></option>")
                   .attr("value",taskId)
                   .text(taskDescription));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="processorTasksId">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>

</select>
<input type="button" id="addTaskButton" value="Add" /> 

<table id="tasksTable">

</table>
```